# Prism 6.3 Wpf : Setting regionMangers active view fails because of missing view name when registering the view

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-6

I want to set the Active View of a Region but im not able to recive the correct name of the View from RegionManger

I register the Views in a Module like this:

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion",typeof(ViewA));
_container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA>("ViewA");          
_container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewB>("ViewB");
```

im navigating to ViewB in the "MainRegion".

Later in some method of ViewB im trying to set ViewA as the active view of "MainRegion".

```
var viewA = _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].GetView("ViewA");
_regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Activate(viewA);
```

Im not able to get viewA here. after debugging i found the Name property of the MainRegion.Views to be empty for ViewA and ViewB.

How can i activate ViewA or how to register the views in a way to set the Name properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You register a view for navigation like this

```
_container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA>("ViewA");
```

Then you just request to navigate using `RequestNavigate`:

```
_regionManager?.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", "ViewA");
```

If you want to check if a certain view is in a certain region you can do it like this:

```
regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Views.Any(v => v.GetType() == typeof(ViewA));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesnt solve my problem. Im aware of how to navigate to a view, but i dont want to navigate to ViewA again, i want to show the existing ViewA that is still in the regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"]  without having to do expensive stuff like calling database in OnNavigatedTo() again.

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope I understood you  correct, you want to check if a certain view is in a certain region?

Comment: If yo navigated to a view once and want the same view again, you can just call `RequestNavigate` again and it won't create a new instance of the view, but keep the previous in the same state.

Comment: var view  =_regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Views.First(v => v.GetType() == typeof(ViewA));
            _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Activate(view);